# Stuck upgrading to 5.24.1 on Joomla

Tags: joomla, upgrade

I am stuck at database upgrade. I deleted the cache before (though FTP) as it says and the progressbar is stuck at this: [Executed: Drop column "civicrm_domain.config_backend"]
I increased execution time to 20000

Civilog under media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/say this:

```
       Apr 08 12:31:41  [info] $CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX_runNext_error = PEAR_Exception: "DB Error: no such field"
 * ERROR TYPE: DB_Error
 * ERROR CODE: -19
 * ERROR MESSAGE: DB Error: no such field
 * ERROR MODE: 16
 * ERROR USERINFO: 
UPDATE civicrm_domain
SET    version = '5.23.alpha1'
 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'config_backend' in 'OLD']
 * ERROR DEBUGINFO: 
UPDATE civicrm_domain
SET    version = '5.23.alpha1'
 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'config_backend' in 'OLD']
#0 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#1 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(997): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "\nUPDATE civicrm_domain\nSET    version = '5.23.alpha1'\n [nativecode=1054 **...")
#2 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-19, 16, (Array:2), "\nUPDATE civicrm_domain\nSET    version = '5.23.alpha1'\n [nativecode=1054 **...")
#3 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -19, 16, (Array:2), "\nUPDATE civicrm_domain\nSET    version = '5.23.alpha1'\n [nativecode=1054 **...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#4 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1925): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#5 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(935): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, "\nUPDATE civicrm_domain\nSET    version = '5.23.alpha1'\n [nativecode=1054 **...", "1054 ** Unknown column 'config_backend' in 'OLD'")
#6 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(405): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#7 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1231): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("\nUPDATE civicrm_domain\nSET    version = '5.23.alpha1'\n")
#8 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2691): DB_common->query("\nUPDATE civicrm_domain\nSET    version = '5.23.alpha1'\n")
#9 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1829): DB_DataObject->_query("\nUPDATE civicrm_domain\nSET    version = '5.23.alpha1'\n")
#10 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(421): DB_DataObject->query("\nUPDATE civicrm_domain\nSET    version = '5.23.alpha1'\n")
#11 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1408): CRM_Core_DAO->query("\nUPDATE civicrm_domain\nSET    version = '5.23.alpha1'\n", TRUE)
#12 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php(260): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("\nUPDATE civicrm_domain\nSET    version = '5.23.alpha1'\n")
#13 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php(275): CRM_Upgrade_Form->runQuery("\nUPDATE civicrm_domain\nSET    version = '5.23.alpha1'\n")
#14 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php(772): CRM_Upgrade_Form->setVersion("5.23.alpha1")
#15 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php(74): CRM_Upgrade_Form::doIncrementalUpgradeFinish(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), "5.23.alpha1", "5.22.1", "5.24.1", "/tmp/civicrm-post-upgradedxKKex")
#16 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php(202): CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))
#17 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(36): CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(TRUE)
#18 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php(90): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()
#19 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(38): CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))
#20 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(234): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()
#21 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#22 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:5))
#23 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(121): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:5))
#24 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
#25 /home/mydirectory/public_html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(402): require_once("/home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#26 /home/mydirectory/public_html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(377): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#27 /home/mydirectory/public_html/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(101): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#28 /home/mydirectory/public_html/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(159): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()
#29 /home/mydirectory/public_html/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(196): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()
#30 /home/mydirectory/public_html/administrator/index.php(51): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
#31 {main}
```

Any help please

Comment: Ok, now I actually managed to get to the backend and Civi says its database is partially upgraded. Retrying gives me this: Database check failed - the database looks to have been partially upgraded. You may want to reload the database with the backup and try the upgrade process again.

Comment: So you tried the upgrade, it failed, you increased the timeout and now rerunning gives this error?  If so, go back to the log for the first run and see what is reported around the 'Drop column civicrm_domain.config_backend'   Looks like it succeeded in dropping that column first time. Also, do you have logging enabled at Administer > System Settings > Misc?  If so, disable logging & re-enable

Comment: @aidan I think you're right about logging. There was an upgrade step at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15842/files#diff-2cbb1d9cc3ea352d50c109fc5ec3efb1R87 that drops config_backend but the supporting function in core doesn't take log tables into account (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.24.1/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/Base.php#L236) so I think this is a core bug. I'm going to make a ticket.

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1698 There is a final reconciliation at the end for log tables, so normally it's not a problem, but that happens after it tries to update civicrm_domain.version, which happens to be in the same table as config_backend.

Comment: Today I tried in Xampp and exactly the same thing happened, database upgrade said this: [Error: Finish Upgrade DB to 5.23.alpha1]
Error 1: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Error.php, line 805. The line there says this : while (is_callable([$ei, 'getCause'])) {
        // DB_ERROR doesn't have a getCause but does have a __call function which tricks is_callable.

Comment: So if its really buggy is it possible to delete Civi(with sql tables together), install new version and import tables that I need? I only need contacts and groups, tags, members. No other feature is used so far (no payment, contribution, cases, mail, campaging, event) I mean, did these (ontacts and groups, tags, members) tables change at all since 5.22.1 version?

Comment: What I would do temporarily is what Aidan suggested and turn off logging at Administer > System Settings > Misc, then run the upgrade, then turn logging back on. If that doesn't work then you could temporarily comment out this line before the upgrade: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.24.1/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FiveTwentyThree.php#L89

Comment: Wow! I took all safety measures, backed up everything, created a local copy in xampp, and then turned off logging as you guys suggested and voila in 20 seconds it upgraded without any problems. Problem solved.